# "ignore_changes" feature for secrets in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, argoproj

I have this very simple secret definition

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysecret
data:
  username: YWRtaW4=
  password: MWYyZDFlMmU2N2Rm
```

I want to keep the definition of the secret in my git repo but obviously real values should not be committed and this file only should provide some default values.

I have a tool that applies all k8s files in the corresponding directory.
This tool every time restores initial value thus reverting my manual changes.

I would like to check if there is a way to ignore value changes for the secret.
E.g. in terraform there is "ignore_changes" flag for that exact reason.

For the full picture: I am using:

- Rancher  - to view/modify single resources
- Argo - to synchronize the k8s manifest files to the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your k8s Version, you may try the Immutable Secrets: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#secret-immutable

I can't tell you if trying to overwrite the secret would cause an error.

Depending on if this is your own image, you may also use two different secrets, the default one, and one that is created manually. Both get mounted into the pods, but the manual will take precedence.